# Function call on non-indexed column in where clause will affect the performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I understand that if we use function call on indexed column in where clause, SQL server engine will ignored that index and perform the scan operation instead of seek.

Just I need understand, 
Will function call on non-indexed column in where clause will affect the performance?

Answer (score 0):

A function call on a non indexed column will only impact the performance insofar as the overhead of the function call itself.  Making the function call on that column cannot preclude the use of an index which did not exist in the first place.

You said:

> SQL server engine will ignored that index and perform the scan operation instead of seek.

A slight correction is that SQL Server does not support function based indices (though Oracle and a few other databases do).  In SQL Server, if you want a function based index, you may workaround by using a materialized view.

Comment: Another workaround is computed column and index on top of it